# Is there a standard pointer size declaration?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, standards

I have struct with padding in `char` (oops, my bad). I would like to subtract a pointer size. Do you know a standard pointer size declaration, or a standard macro for that?

Comment: Why don't you post your code for clearer feedback - to make sure you are not layering one error on top of another?

Comment: there are various SIZEOF_VOID_P in /usr/include, that is something I was thinking about

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`sizeof (void *)`

Answer (score 9):

Do you want the C-standard answer, or the answer that works pretty much all the time?

Usually, all pointers to data are the same size, which is `sizeof(void*)`.

But since you tagged "C" and "standards", note that this is not required by the C standard. I think it is required by POSIX, and is also true on Win32, and none of the common modern architectures have instructions involving different-sized pointers. One scenario where you have different-sized pointers is segmented memory architectures with "near" and "far" pointers, although of course only one of those can be a "plain" pointer in C on any given implementation. Another scenario, is that in theory a pointer to `int` could be 2 bits smaller than a pointer to `char`, if an int is always 4-aligned. If the memory space was, say, 64MB, that could mean that an `int*` fits in 2 bytes, whereas a `char*` or `void*` requires 3. So the C standard allows different sizes for different types, in this case `sizeof(int*) < sizeof(char*)`.

So, both for clarity, and a guarantee of correctness, if `p` is a pointer then its size is `sizeof p`.

As Steve Townsend says in his comment, it seems likely that if you ask another question about your code, you may be able to fix your real problem. Knowing the size of a pointer *does not* directly tell you much about the layout of a struct containing a pointer.

Comment: Right, but a `void*` should be large enough to be able to hold any other pointer, so I think `sizeof(void *)` will always work in practice.

Comment: @Conrad: depends what you mean by "work". If you just need a number that's at least as big as any pointer, there's `SIZE_MAX` ;-) If you need the exact size of a particular pointer...

Comment: Right -- I guess I was just assuming he wanted to have enough space for an arbitrary pointer type in some struct or something like that. (In which case, a `void*` member makes sense.)

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a portable way to find the offset in bytes of a structure member then you want to use the `offsetof()` macro defined in `stddef.h`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int main(void)
{
    struct s {
        int i;
        char c;
        double d;
        char a[];
    };

    /* Output is compiler dependent */

    printf("offsets: i=%ld; c=%ld; d=%ld a=%ld\n",
            (long) offsetof(struct s, i),
            (long) offsetof(struct s, c),
            (long) offsetof(struct s, d),
            (long) offsetof(struct s, a));
    printf("sizeof(struct s)=%ld\n", (long) sizeof(struct s));

    return 0;
}
```

#### Output

```
$ ./a.out
offsets: i=0; c=4; d=8 a=16
sizeof(struct s)=16
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sizeof(void*)` directly.