# Byte size of a pointer to pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

What is the byte size of a pointer to pointer? Is it the same as the byte size of a regular pointer(typically 4 on a 32bit machine, 8 on a 64bit machine - although not always)?

For example:

```
int *p;
int **q;
```

what would the pointer to pointer q be?

Comment: What's your guess? A pointer to a pointer is just a regular pointer after all.

Comment: sizeof(p) == sizeof(q)

Comment: Though to be strictly standard pedantic, I don't think the standard says that all pointers are the same size.

Comment: All object pointers are the same size.  Function pointers need not be the same size as object pointers.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Not true. On old Crays, for architectural reasons not different from modern GPU vector processors, addressing a single `char` took more bits than addressing a vector word.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306369/is-there-a-standard-pointer-size-declaration

Comment: @Potatoswatter: C99 §6.5.2 Types, ¶26 _A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as a
pointer to a character type. Similarly, pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements. All pointers to structure types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other. All pointers to union types shall have the same representation and alignment requirements as each other. Pointers to other types need not have the same representation or alignment requirements._

Comment: So yup...[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_12) requires:  2.12.3 **Pointer Types**

_All function pointer types shall have the same representation as the type pointer to void. Conversion of a function pointer to `void *` shall not alter the representation. A `void *` value resulting from such a conversion can be converted back to the original function pointer type, using an explicit cast, without loss of information._

Comment: It might help if we knew why you cared what size pointers are. It could affect your answers a lot.

Answer (score 7):

Standard does not guarantee the size of pointers to be equal. It only guarantees the sizeof(char) to be equal to 1.

So size of `int *` need not be same as size of `float *`.

So to answer your question **size of a `int *` is not 'guaranteed' to be equal to size of `int  **`**.

But on most compilers size of `int *` is equal to size of `int **`

**Here is a piece from C99 : 
6.2.5.26**

> A pointer to void shall have the same representation and alignment
>   requirements as a pointer to a character type.(39) Similarly, pointers
>   to qualified or unqualified versions  of compatible types shall have
>   the same representation and alignment requirements. All  pointers to
>   structure types shall have the same representation and alignment
>   requirements  as each other. All pointers to union types shall have
>   the same representation and alignment requirements as each other.
>   Pointers to other types need not have the same representation or
>   alignment requirements.
>
> 39)The same representation and alignment requirements are meant to
>   imply interchangeability as arguments to functions, return values from
>   functions, and members of unions.

Comment: @MitchWheat The standard specifies what you can do, not necessarily what you cannot do or what quantities might not be equal to each other. So a counterargument to this answer would require a reference, but this is good enough.

Comment: @MitchWheat For C++, this is as close as you can get: "The value representation of pointer types is implementation-defined. Pointers to cv-qualified and cv-unqualified versions (3.9.3) of layout-compatible types shall have the same value representation and alignment requirements (3.11)." — by omitting any stricter requirement, any other kind of wackiness is allowed.

Comment: Some compilers on weird — and possibly now obsolete — architectures make `sizeof(char*)` _larger_ than `sizeof(void*)`. There was some kind of Cray (IIRC) where the smallest actually addressable unit was a machine word of 32 bits, so a `char*` was really a struct of a pointer and an offset into the word (so that the bit stuffing would work); this resulted in some crazy bug reports to me from the guys that had this particular system. Just when you think you know how peculiar things can get, they get stranger! (And no, I wouldn't be surprised if this wasn't standard-compliant C.)

Answer (score -2):

You didn't specify exactly what language version you are asking about. C99 sez:

> A pointer to an object or incomplete type may be converted to a
>   pointer to a different object or incomplete type. If the resulting
>   pointer is not correctly aligned57) for the pointed-to type, the
>   behavior is undefined. Otherwise, when converted back again, the
>   result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

in section 6.3.2.3

That kinda guarantees that all pointers are sure going to act like they're the same size.

Well, no. As potatoswatter pointed out. The conversion-ability does not guarantee same sizes.

Comment: No, because the alignment requirement may relieve stricter pointer types of having bits required to store values only possible for looser pointer types. C apparently is more tolerant than C++, but it still allows `sizeof(char*) != sizeof(int*)`.

Comment: well, modulo pointers to functions.

Comment: @Potatoswatter thank you, you're right. Additionally, func pointers must all have the same representation, and all flavors of char pointers must share the same representation.

Comment: Conversion might result in a change in representation. I fail to see how this quote proves that all pointer representations are identical.

Comment: By that logic, `char c = 0; int i = c;` since c can be safely converted to an int and stored in i, c and i are the same size.