# Is alignof(T*) is the same for all possible types? What about sizeof(T*)?

Tags: c++, pointers, language-lawyer, sizeof, alignof

Is `alignof(T*)` is the same value for all possible types `T`? What about `sizeof(T*)`?
Please answer based on what is allowed/specified by the standard and not what is the current situation in different compilers.

Comment: IIRC, the answer can be different for pointers to functions, and regular (data) pointers.

Comment: Pointer sizes (and alignment) can be trickier than than first appears, so care needs to be taken. C++ introduces more types of pointers on top of the C-Memory model (for example, a pointer to member-field, is NOT the same size as void*). I think you need to provide more details. Are you only talking about POD-pointers (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/PODType)? For a full-feature handling of C++ pointers you will need to go via std::function.

Comment: It seems you think there are categories (?) Like for all POD it is the same, for all member-fields it is the same, .... Is that true? can you list those categories?

Comment: I don't think it is mandate to be the same, some require to be convertible to `void*` (and back to original pointer) which adds some relationship.

Comment: @Tiger4Hire pointers to members are not pointers though, confusingly :) i.e. they are not `T*`. Only object pointers and function pointers are pointer types.

Comment: Yes, there are different categories. Certain objects are required to be compatible with their C equivalents, and so are defined by the C-Standard. You can broadly split pointers into "C-pointers" and "C++-pointers". The standard changed with regard to this in C++20, but prior to that, anything that was "POD" (including pointers to POD-data) had much stricter requirements.

Comment: Answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306369/is-there-a-standard-pointer-size-declaration

Comment: The link you say contains the answer, only talks about `sizeof` and nothing about `alignof`. Even for `sizeof` it does not seem a complete answer. The selected answer is yes, they are all equal to `sizeof(void*)` and gives zero explanation or reference for it. There is another answer that says no (according to the standard), but it does not say there are categories, which is what you said earlier.

Comment: On a system with 128K RAM, it might have 3-byte `void *` and 2-byte `int *` (which must be aligned to 2)

Comment: There is nothing in the standard that requires that all pointers have the same size. On word-addressed systems, `sizeof(char*)` and `sizeof(short*)` will be larger than `sizeof(int*)`. You can apply logic to the standard to infer that all structure pointers are the same size due to the existence of pointers to incomplete types. And the standard does require that [`void*` have the same size and alignment as `char*`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/basic.compound#5).

Answer (score 3):

The standard doesn't say much about sizes and alignments of pointers, and thus they are not strictly restricted by the language.

Conversion from one valid pointer to function into another and back is guaranteed to produce the original value. As such, there must be the same minimum number of values that must be representable that is the maximum number of valid addresses for any given pointer to function type which gives lower bound to the size of all pointer to function types.

Conversions between object types have a similar guarantee, which however only applies when the original pointed type has stricter or equal alignment requirement. As a consequence, object pointers to highly aligned types require fewer representable values. If the alignment is high enough, then the type could in theory be smaller.

On systems where conversion between pointer to void and pointer to function is allowed (which is conditionally supported), the minimum number of representable values of pointers to functions and pointers to void must be the same.

But even so, some pointer types could be larger than the number of representable values it needs. Those extra bits would simply necessarily be unused. This would not be very practical.